# Redefine caption in order to accept terms in italic

Tags: captions, italic

There is a way to make the caption of figures accept terms in italic?
I've tried commands such as

```
\emph{}
\textit{}
```

But none of them worked. Here is what I am trying to do, as well the result I get.

```
\caption{Exemplificação de um \emph{grid} bidimensional constituído por \emph{blocks} bidimensionais.}
```

[image]

The document class that I am using is

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\ProvidesClass{abntex2}[2018/11/24 v-1.9.7 abnTeX2]
```

And the caption configuration

```
\newcommand{\IBGEtabfontsize}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida}
\newcommand{\ABNTEXcaptiondelim}{~\textendash~}

\AtEndPackage{caption}{
      \AtBeginDocument{%
        \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{barr}{\ABNTEXcaptiondelim}
        \DeclareCaptionFont{ABNTEXfontereduzida}{\ABNTEXfontereduzida}
          \captionsetup{format=hang,
                        labelseparator=barr,
                        labelfont=bf,
                        textfont=bf
                        }
          \renewcommand{\configurecaptions}{%
                      \captionsetup{justification=justified,%
                                    singlelinecheck=false}}
          \renewcommand{\configureseparator}{\captionsetup{labelsep=colon}}
      }
}
```

If I delete the "textfont=bf" from \captionsetup, the italic works fine with the previous \caption command:

[image]

However, I need the caption to be entire bold and with some terms in italic.
Does someone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: You need a font that has bold italics.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the package

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and now the text in italic+bold works fine!